# What words can I use to express a "great time"?

Tags: expressions

What words can I use to express a "great time"?

I am trying to write an essay and I just need words that expresses a great time to make the essay sound interesting.

Comment: Do you mean a long time, or a very enjoyable time (as in _We had a great time at Disney World_)?

Answer (score 2):

Try these, in rough order of length of time:

- A while
- Ages
- Years
- a donkey's age
- Centuries
- Millennia
- Since before Adam
- Geological time
- eons
- epoch (added on the suggestion of Marv Mills)
- eternity
- forever
- for ever and ever, amen.

Comment: You missed 'Epoch'...

Comment: I think of epochs as shorter than eons and those are shorter than geological time.